# Direct connection or using capacitor when shorting PSU's DC negative terminal to earth terminal?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have read and then observed that for reducing the 50Hz related noise, tying the -DC terminal of an SMPS supply to the earth terminal woks well in some cases when. Below shows a direct path by a wire between the negative DC terminal and the earth terminal of the supply:

[image]

But I have also seen some uses 100nF capacitors instead of wiring directly. Is there a particular reason for using capacitor instead of directly tying these terminals by a wire?

Answer (score 0):

Capacitor is used as bypass capacitor to eliminate stray current from the psu.

the point is the earth and the negative terminal should be at same potential that is zero. if there is any spike in the voltage on negative terminal due to reference issue the capacitor will store the charge inside it

Comment: Im not talking about the Y capacitor inside the supply. The cap I mention is an external one where the user ties the cap in between the -DC and the earth terminals of the PSU. Also your one sentence answer is not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a giagram of some of the most troublesome currents, the fastest currents, inside
a switching power supply. How to reduce the movements of these currents?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZOB2i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In some SMPS, even the heatsink is directly attached to the Power MOSFET drain, with no insulating plastic layer; in such cases, even the heatsink is a Efield radiator.

Comment: Can you name the terminals? Which one is earth which one is DC negative terminal ect? And Im asking what is the effect of cap isntead of direct wiring. Because I observed no difference in  practice.

Comment: But do you mean the C6 is connected to earth terminal? Why not direct connection why 100nF? Im talking about 50Hz noise or 100Hz not high freq. switching noise

Comment: There will be coupled energy across the transformer. Some of that energy will be 50Hz, and will take all possible return paths.